# My programming question on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[Programmatically execute Chrome's "Add to Home Screen" shortcut from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385201/programatically-execute-chrome-shortcut-on-android-using-android-studio)

Why is this on hold? Their answer is "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming".

Android Studio is definitely a tool used for programming, and my question is about how to programmatically how to do something. What's up?

Comment: Instead of "my question is about how to programmatically how to do something", don't you mean "my question is about how to programmatically do something"?

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit of a jumble.

If I understand you correctly...You want to invoke a shortcut link generated from Chrome's "Add to Home Screen" feature programmatically.

That's not necessarily a bad question in and of itself - it took a few passes but I was able to at least figure it out - but it's missing a few things:

- There's no indication of what Android version you're running.  Or Chrome, for that matter.
- There's no indication of what you've attempted to do, either in the form of code, or some API calls you were researching.

  (I'd argue that this kind of question doesn't *entirely* demand code, but *some* research would be nice to see.)
- The way the question reads is confusing; you mention Android Studio several times but it doesn't actually *add* to the question at all.

The close reason is wrong but I do feel like you still need to fix the question up.  I can make a good-faith effort to edit it into what it seems like you're looking for; I have to leave the important parts - Android version among others - as your task.

Comment: We have tablets out in the field, a lot of them, and the solution would be deployed to all of them. They are not just one OS, we have some at 4.4.2 (which won't update past this), some 5.02, maybe some at others. Our tech guys don't even know all the OS's. The Chrome version, at least on the one I am looking at is 43...not sure about the others. Ideally OS version and Chrome version won't matter...hoping for just 1 solution. I mention Android Studio because I don't know if other apps like Cordova or Xamarin might do it differently. Found some similar questions to this, but no one had answers.

Comment: "There's no indication of what Android version you're running. Or Chrome, for that matter." - Is that information vital to an answer, i.e., will the answer differ for different combinations? If this may be the case, @E.D., you may want to edit your comment above into your question. FWIW as far as I can see it'll still be a fairly broad "how do I do this", which may or may not receive an answer.